# Java SockJS Spring client and message size

Tags: spring, websocket, spring-websocket, sockjs

Using SockJS java client, I am trying to connect to Spring sockjs server and is getting error 1009 for messages (without headers) of ~20Kb. Javascript library works fine.

```
Transport closed with CloseStatus[code=1009, reason=The decoded text message was too big 
for the output buffer and the endpoint does not support partial messages] in WebSocketClientSockJsSession
[id='9fa30eb453e14a8c8612e1064640646a, url=ws://127.0.0.1:8083/user]
```

I have couple of config classes on server (I do not know at the moment if I am configuring these things more times than necessary):

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocket
public class WebSocketTransportConfig implements WebSocketConfigurer {
    // Important web socket setup. If big message is coming through, it may overflow the buffer and this will lead in disconnect.
    // All messages that are coming through normally (including snapshots) must be order of magnitude smaller, or connection will be broken
    // sometimes
    // There is also MaxBinaryMessageSize that we do not employ as we use Stomp, but for completeness it is also set to same values.
    // Javadoc http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/socket/adapter/jetty/JettyWebSocketSession.html#setTextMessageSizeLimit-int-

    public static final int MAX_TEXT_MESSAGE_SIZE = 2048000; // 2 Megabytes.
    public static final int BUFFER_SIZE = MAX_TEXT_MESSAGE_SIZE * 5;


    private static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(WebSocketTransportConfig.class);

    @Override
    public void registerWebSocketHandlers(WebSocketHandlerRegistry registry) {

    }

    @Bean
    public DefaultHandshakeHandler handshakeHandler() {
        LOGGER.info("Websocket buffer size: " + BUFFER_SIZE + " bytes.");
        WebSocketPolicy policy = new WebSocketPolicy(WebSocketBehavior.SERVER);
        policy.setMaxTextMessageBufferSize(BUFFER_SIZE);
        policy.setMaxTextMessageSize(MAX_TEXT_MESSAGE_SIZE);
        policy.setMaxBinaryMessageBufferSize(BUFFER_SIZE);
        policy.setMaxBinaryMessageSize(MAX_TEXT_MESSAGE_SIZE);
        policy.setInputBufferSize( BUFFER_SIZE);
        policy.setIdleTimeout(600000);

        return new DefaultHandshakeHandler(
                new JettyRequestUpgradeStrategy(new WebSocketServerFactory(policy)));
    }
}
```

and

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
@EnableScheduling
public class WebSocketBrokerConfig extends WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurationSupport implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {


    @Override
    public void configureWebSocketTransport(WebSocketTransportRegistration registry) {
        // Increase buffers. 
        // Too little buffers may result in fatal errros when transmitting relatively large messages.
        registry.setMessageSizeLimit(WebSocketTransportConfig.MAX_TEXT_MESSAGE_SIZE);
        registry.setSendBufferSizeLimit(WebSocketTransportConfig.BUFFER_SIZE);
        super.configureWebSocketTransport(registry);
    }
}
```

According to [Stomp spring web socket message exceeds size limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34343235/stomp-spring-web-socket-message-exceeds-size-limit) that should help but when connecting Java Spring SockJS client, I still get error 1009 (too big message).

I suspect therefore I may have one of two issues:

1. Java SockJS client must be also configured to RECEIVE bigger messages.
2. Or, I am still misconfigured on server.

How can I increase buffer size on Java SockJS Spring client?

Comment: Have you resolved it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I stumbled with the same problem. It's all about the configuration of the client, not the server.
You can create *WebSocketContainer* instance and configure it.

```
WebSocketContainer container = ContainerProvider.getWebSocketContainer();
container.setDefaultMaxBinaryMessageBufferSize(your_size);
container.setDefaultMaxTextMessageBufferSize(your_size);
WebSocketClient transport = new StandardWebSocketClient(container);
WebSocketStompClient stompClient = new WebSocketStompClient(transport);
```

your_size - size in bytes.

Comment: Thank you VERY much!  This solved my problem. I was trying to send a large sized STOMP message and this solved the issue!

Comment: Although the answer was long ago, it saves my day!

Comment: Any idea on a recommended max size to not exceed?

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing it like this:

```
SockJsClient sockJsClient = new SockJsClient(transports);
    WebSocketStompClient stompClient = new WebSocketStompClient(sockJsClient);
```

Try:

```
stompClient.setInboundMessageSizeLimit(your_message_size_limit);
```

Comment: this doesn't help